# VBA to keep format when copying shapes from Powerpoint to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to copy shapes from a Powerpoint presentation to an Excel template using Excel VBA macros. However, I am not able to keep the formats from the original Powerpoint source.

This is the code I've got so far

```
    Public Sub test()

    Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim p As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim s As Slide
    Dim aux_vec as Variant
    Dim wkbk as Workbook

    Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:=src, ReadOnly:=True
    Workbooks.Open "template.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True
    Set wkbk = ActiveWorkbook

    PPT.Activate
    Set s = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(1) 'Slide to be copied

    ReDim aux_vec(s.Shapes.Count)
    For i = 1 To s.Shapes.Count
        aux_vec(i) = i
    Next i

    s.Shapes.Range(aux_vec).Copy
    Set wks = wkbk.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Destination sheet
    wks.Select
    wks.Range("C3").Select
    wks.PasteSpecial 5 ' <--- Changes theme

    End Sub
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Fixed the code Snippet after comment by Ryan B.

Comment: Tried that too, but still had the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround:
I exported the theme used in the Powerpoint presentation and imported it in Excel. This way the shapes keep their formats. Not optimal, but it worked for me.

Comment: When a shape is assiged a theme color, it's really just an index into the current theme palette, not an actual RGB color. If you bring the shape into a different app or another pressie with a different them, the index may point to the same place but there'll be different RGB values there. You can probably get around this by picking up the PPT shape's RGB fill and line colors and assigning them to the pasted shape in Excel.